# I can't get data with where condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

I need to get result by this :

```
$datenow = $request->date;
$payment = Payment::where('date',$datenow)->get();
```

when I try this I got :

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1847 ▼ // app\Http\Controllers\DateController.php:56
      #items: []
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

but I try this once it work:

```
$payment = Payment::where('date','2021-10-03')->get();
```

I cant get the data with the where condition

Comment: check what value is getting from $datenow

Comment: 2021-10-03 i got this in $datenow

Comment: What does `dd($datenow)` give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that $request->date is in the correct format ('Y-m-d') which is the format that SQL uses for dates. You can do this by using the `date()` function in PHP.

```
$datenow = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->date));
$payment = Payment::where('date', $datenow)->get();
```

Or you can use Carbon to ake sure the format is the same as the one in the database.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

// ...

$datenow = Carbon::parse($request->date)->format('Y-m-d');
$payment = Payment::where('date', $datenow)->get();
```

Comment: it's output is only one date "1970-01-01"